# How do I stop my elements (Logo / Navigation Bar / Header) from moving when I resize the browser window?

Tags: html, css

I'm still very new to coding and learning it myself. I heavily appreciate any help I can get. Thank you !!

I am trying to figure out what I need to change and especially which kind of units I should use to position my elements in a way where they don't move when I resize the browser window.

PS: If you find any spare time could you kindly explain to me how I can make the page look the same in most modern browsers? Thank you!

```css
    * {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    
                                        /* BODY */
    
    body {
        background-image: url(curtain1.jpg);
        background-position: 0 200px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    
                                        /* HEADER 1 */
    
    .headers h1 {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-display: swap;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        top: 7.5%;
        left: 5%;
        float: left;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
                                        /* HEADER 2*/
    
    .headers h2 {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-style: normal;
        font-display: auto;
        font-size: 20px;
        top: 15.5%;
        left: 4.35%;
        font-style: oblique;
        float: left;
        color: bisque;
        width: auto;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
    }
    
                                            /* LOGO */
    
    .headers img {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: -90px;
        border: none;
        width: 180px;
        max-width: 160px;
        max-height: 135px;
        height: 135px;
        background: #555;
        position: absolute;
        top: 4.5%;
        z-index: 1000;
        left: 50%;
        right: 50%;
        
    }
    
                                            /* NAVIGATION BAR */
    
    .navigationbar {
        list-style:none;
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding:0;
        float:left;
        top: 20.5%;
        width: 1206.16px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -600px;
        min-width: 970px;
        font-family: "Bungee Hairline", cursive;
        border: 10px solid white;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    .navigationbar li {   
        float:left;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:0;
        border-right: 1px solid white;
    
    }
    
    .navigationbar li a { 
        display:inline;
        float:left;
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:0;
        padding:9px 13px;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-transform:capitalize;
        text-align:center;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:24px;
        font-style:normal;
        color:#F2EFEF;
        border-right:1px dotted #060606;
        background:#222121;
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(#131212,0),color-   stop(#222121,0.4),color-stop(#474646,0.8),color-stop(#3C3939,1));
        background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#131212 0%,#222121 40%,#474646 80%,#3C3939 100%);
        background:   -moz-linear-gradient(top,#131212 0%,#222121 40%,#474646 80%,#3C3939 100%);
        background:     -o-linear-gradient(top,#131212 0%,#222121 40%,#474646 80%,#3C3939 100%);
        background:        linear-gradient(top,#131212 0%,#222121 40%,#474646 80%,#3C3939 100%);
    
        -moz-transition:0.5s ease-out;
        -webkit-transition:0.5s ease-out;
        transition:0.5s ease-out;
    }
    
    .navigationbar li a:hover, .navigationbar li a:active {
        background-color: red;
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(#3047DB,0),color-stop(#3088DB,0.4),color-stop(#48AAE7,0.8),color-stop(#48BAE7,1));
        background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,red, 0%,red 40%,#red 80%,red 100%);
        background:   -moz-linear-gradient(top,#3047DB 0%,red 40%,red 80%,red 100%);
        background:     -o-linear-gradient(top,red 0%,red 40%,red 80%,red 100%);
        background:        linear-gradient(top,red 0%,red 40%,red 80%,red 100%);
        color:#97410F;
        -moz-transition:0.5s ease-in;
        -webkit-transition:0.5s ease-in;
        transition:0.5s ease-in;
        border-right:1px solid transparent;
    }
    
                                            /* Phone Vector + Number */
    
    #phoneimg {
        position: absolute;
        right: 5%;
        top: 7.5%;
        margin-right: 1.7%
        
    }
    
    #phonenumber {
        position: absolute;
        right: 5%;
        top: 15%;
    }
    
                                            /* Body Content */
    
    #blackbox {
        width: 1206px;
        height: 1000px;
        color: black;
        background-color: black;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        right: 50%;
        margin-left: -590px;
        top: 23%;
        z-index: -100;
    }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
                <!--This is the TAB Content-->
        
      <title>XOXO - Exciting Companions</title>
        
                <!--Link the CSS File here-->
      
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        
                <!--Link Google Fonts here-->
        
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Hairline|Crushed" rel="stylesheet">
        
    </head>
        
    <body>
        
                <!--  PHONE VECTOR PHONE NUMBER-->
        
        <div class="phonenr">
            
            <div id="phoneimg">
            
            <img src="iphonevector.jpeg" id="phone" style="height:50px;width:50px;"/>
            
            </div>
            
            <div id="phonenumber">
            
                <p>+44 1234 567 89</p>
            
            </div>
            
            </div>
        
        <div class="headers">
            
            <!--LOGO XOXO-->
            
            <div id="logo">
                    
                    <img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" height="115px" width="135px" />
                     <h1>XOXO</h1>
                     <h2>London Escorts</h2>
            </div>
        
        </div>
        
                <!-- NAVIGATION MENU BAR-->
        
    <div class="navigationbar">
        
        <ul>
            
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">All Escorts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tonight's Escorts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bookings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Price</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            
    </ul>
        
        </div>    
        
                <!--This is the HomePage Content Div-->
        
        <div class="BodyContent">
            
            <div id="blackbox"></div>
            
            </div>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Avoid using `absolute` positioning for building layouts. Take some time and look at [this website](http://learnlayout.com/) about creating CSS layouts

Comment: I don't understand what means "in a way where [the elements] don't move".  You want that your site doesn't adapt itself when the window is resized ? This would mean that a part of the content is hidden. Is that what you want ?

Comment: Zgood: Thank you I appreciate the help this website you recommended is very helpful!

Comment: Eria: Yes that is what I meant, I would like to avoid the elements from being squished together when I resize the browser window.